# Android OpenSL Buffer Timeout

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opensl

For the last few weeks I'm trying to learn more about OpenSL. Wrote a simple music player, and it worked really well.

On some devices, I'm receiving an error message and the OpenSL thread gets locked, which also locks the UI thread for some reason and I have to force close or wait for the non responsive popup message to close the app. This happens rarely on some devices, and extremely often on an Asus Nexus tablet.

The error message is

```
I/SoftAAC2( 6431): Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
D/dalvikvm(  490): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1918K, 24% free 19375K/25308K, paused 87ms, total 89ms
I/AudioFlinger(  125): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4100) from active list on thread 0x41963008
I/audio_a2dp_hw(  125): suspend_audio_datapath: state 1
```

This message is al there is, nothing descriptive.

As I can only use OpenSL from JNI part, is there a way to detect the BUFFER TIMEOUT message and close the appropriate thread from C code?